# Opening a new activity gives null object reference

Tags: java, android

The app is supposed to open a new activity by clicking `RecyclerView`. but when I try to click on my  `RecyclerView` data, it gives the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.studyreminder.CustomAdapter$1.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:69)
```

I'm using fragments if that makes any difference.
I don't understand how to fix so if anyone knows it will be appreciated.

Class where the error is at:

```
        public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.myViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList task_id, task_subject, task_description, task_due_date;
    private Activity activity;
    ImageButton deleteTask;
    String task;

    CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList task_id, ArrayList task_subject, ArrayList task_description, ArrayList task_due_date){
        this.context = context;
        this.task_id = task_id;
        this.task_description = task_description;
        this.task_subject = task_subject;
        this.task_due_date = task_due_date;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from (context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_do_list, parent, false);
        return new myViewHolder(view);

    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.taskid_txt.setText(String.valueOf(task_id.get(position)));
        holder.taskSubject_txt.setText(String.valueOf(task_subject.get(position)));
        holder.taskDescription_txt.setText(String.valueOf(task_description.get(position)));
        holder.taskDate_txt.setText(String.valueOf(task_due_date.get(position)));
        holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(task_id.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("subject", String.valueOf(task_subject.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("description", String.valueOf(task_description.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("dueDate", String.valueOf(task_due_date.get(position)));
                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return task_id.size();
    }

    public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView taskid_txt, taskSubject_txt, taskDescription_txt, taskDate_txt;
        LinearLayout mainLayout;

        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            taskid_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskid_txt);
            taskSubject_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskSubject_txt);
            taskDescription_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskDescription_txt);
            taskDate_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskDate_txt);
            mainLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        }
    }
}
```

The activity I'm trying to open:

```
public class UpdateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText title_input, author_input, pages_input;
    Button addBtn2, delete_button;
    EditText descEntry2, dateEntry2;
    Spinner sp2;
    String id, description, dueDate, subject;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

        descEntry2 = findViewById(R.id.descEntry2);
        dateEntry2 = findViewById(R.id.dateEntry2);
        addBtn2= findViewById(R.id.addbtn2);
        sp2 = findViewById(R.id.subjectEntry2);
        delete_button = findViewById(R.id.delete_button);

        //First we call this
        getAndSetIntentData();

        //Set actionbar title after getAndSetIntentData method
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        if (ab != null) {
            ab.setTitle(subject);
        }

        addBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //And only then we call this
                MyDatabase myDB = new MyDatabase(UpdateActivity.this);
                description = descEntry2.getText().toString().trim();
                dueDate =dateEntry2.getText().toString().trim();
                subject = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
                myDB.updateData(id, subject, description, dueDate);
            }
        });
        delete_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                confirmDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    void getAndSetIntentData(){
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("id")
                && getIntent().hasExtra("subject")
                && getIntent().hasExtra("description")
                && getIntent().hasExtra("dueDate")){
            //Getting Data from Intent
            id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
            subject = getIntent().getStringExtra("subject");
            description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");
            dueDate = getIntent().getStringExtra("dueDate");

            //Setting Intent Data
            title_input.setText(subject);
            author_input.setText(description);
            pages_input.setText(dueDate);
            Log.d("stev", subject+" "+description+" "+dueDate);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    void confirmDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Delete " + subject + " Task?");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this " + subject + " task?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                MyDatabase myDB = new MyDatabase(UpdateActivity.this);
                myDB.deleteOneRow(subject);
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

XML code for the UpdateActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addTasktxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:text="@string/addTask"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/descEntry2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addbtn2"
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="136dp"
        android:text="Update"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.488"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dateEntry2"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/subjectEntry2"
        android:layout_width="228dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:popupBackground="#5c5c5c"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dateEntry2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/descEntry2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="What needs to be done?"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/subjectEntry2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dateEntry2"
        android:layout_width="104dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="125dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="125dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/taskDueDate"
        android:inputType="phone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subjectEntry2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.486"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addbtn2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateActivity.class);` can you try this?

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales `getApplicationContext()` is red, says cannot resolve method

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales you can start an activity with `Context` but cannot start activity **for result** with `Context`, you can only do that with an `Activity`; and `getApplicationContext()` is not available in class except for those which extend `Context` class

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code. I think your activity object is null. You have not initialize your activity object

```
context.startActivity(intent);

//findViewById() is missing for below variable in UpdateActivity
EditText title_input, author_input, pages_input;
```

Comment: `startActivityForResult` turns red. Says cannot resolve method

Comment: now it gives the following error message:
` java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.studyreminder/com.example.studyreminder.UpdateActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
  at com.example.studyreminder.UpdateActivity.getAndSetIntentData(UpdateActivity.java:76)
        at com.example.studyreminder.UpdateActivity.onCreate(UpdateActivity.java:36)`

Comment: there's a difference between `startActivity` and `startActivityForResult`, @MarkLin wants a result intent

Comment: the error is on editext .EditText.setText. Its not the startActivity() error

Answer (score 0):

you have not intialized `private Activity activity;` in `CustomAdapter` constructor.

either initialize it in ctor or try the snippet below:

try replacing:

```
holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(task_id.get(position)));
        intent.putExtra("subject", String.valueOf(task_subject.get(position)));
        intent.putExtra("description", String.valueOf(task_description.get(position)));
        intent.putExtra("dueDate", String.valueOf(task_due_date.get(position)));
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
});
```

with:

```
holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Context myContext = context == null ? view.getContext() : context;
        Intent intent = new Intent(, UpdateActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(task_id.get(position)));
        intent.putExtra("subject", String.valueOf(task_subject.get(position)));
        intent.putExtra("description", String.valueOf(task_description.get(position)));
        intent.putExtra("dueDate", String.valueOf(task_due_date.get(position)));
        (activity == null ? (Activity)myContext : activity) .startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
});
```